# Supabase - navigate to a file in the storage with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, storage, supabase

I have several folders in the Bucket in Supabase storage, I need to access to the files inside it to get informations, for example :
"user1" Bucket has 3 folders(files , images , notes)..
how I can navigate to the files in the "images" folder and get the informations for all images inside it like (names , types , upload times ...) ;

```
final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;
var  informations= await supabase.storage.from('user1'); // how I can access to the images folder from here and get the infrmations for all files inside of it?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list all files in a bucket: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/storage-from-list

```dart
final List<FileObject> objec = await supabase
  .storage
  .from('user1')
  .list();
```

Comment: It give me a list of the folders inside the bucket (files,images,notes) but how I can access to the files inside these folders ?